# Value assigning to IfcQuantityLength instance in Industry Foundation Classes

Tags: java, ifc

Following is the IFC4 schema. Which can be find [here](http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/final/html/index.htm).

```
<xs:element name="IfcQuantityLength" type="ifc:IfcQuantityLength" substitutionGroup="ifc:IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity" nillable="true"/>
    <xs:complexType name="IfcQuantityLength">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ifc:IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity">
                <xs:attribute name="LengthValue" type="ifc:IfcLengthMeasure" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Formula" type="ifc:IfcLabel" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And in a sample IFC file I found the following line corresponding to `IfcQuantityLength`

```
#68 = IFCQUANTITYLENGTH('Length', 'Length', $, 5000., $);
```

The problem that I am having is why there are 5 params there should be only two params (`LengthValue` and `Formula`), isn't it? What are the other params. And does `$` means value is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the other fields come from `IfcPhysicalSimpleQuantity` which is the parent of `IfcQuantityLength`

Given the `Formula` field is optional, yes I would guess `$` means null.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you consult the IFC specifications which can be found here:
http://www.buildingsmart-tech.org/ifc/IFC4/final/html/schema/ifcquantityresource/lexical/ifcquantitylength.htm
as you will see, this entity, like any other entity, has a series of mandatory and optional fields. Here, there are two optional values which correspond to the $!
It depends on the software/application which generates the data model in IFC format to specify which optional fields are to be filled.